# C# - How to remove spaces when creating new element in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have following code

```
string xml = @"<root>
    <element>Field A</element>
</root>";

string xsl = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
<xsl:template match='root'>
     <root>
         <xsl:variable name='fieldname'>
             <xsl:value-of select='element' />
         </xsl:variable>
             <xsl:element name='{$fieldname}'></xsl:element>
     </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";

XDocument newTree = new XDocument();

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(newTree.CreateWriter()))
{    
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();            
        xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsl)));
        xslt.Transform(XDocument.Parse(xml).CreateReader(), writer);
}
Console.WriteLine(newTree);
```

After it I would like to have such xml

```
<root>
   <FieldA />
</root>
```

Instead I get this error: The ' ' character, hexademical value 0x20, cannot be included in name. 
Look like I need to remove spaces 'Field A' to 'FieldA' before creating new element. 
Tried different variations of replace:

```
replace({@fieldname}, ' ', ''). error: XSLT compile error, Name cannot begin with ''' character, hex 0x27, cannot be included in name.

replace({$fieldname},&apos; &apos;,&apos;&apos;). The '(' character, hex 0x28, cannot be included in name.

<xsl:preserve-space elements="*" /> - Does not help either.
```

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Use the translate function: `<xsl:value-of select="translate(element,' ','')" />`.

This simply translates any spaces into an empty string. Translate is a bit like a text replace, but it only works for individual characters, useful for converting case, or stripping out occurrences of a single character like this.

Comment: Still get this error: XSLT compile error. Name cannot begin with with character ''',hex value 0x27.

Comment: Sorry, my bad; I normally enclose my selects in "", string literals within the expression in '', I accidentally used '' for both. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. translate works. Here is how my final string looks like. string xsltPiece = "<xsl:value-of select='translate(elem," + "\" \", \"\"" + ")' />"